# initializer_list and GCC 4.9.2 vs GCC trunk

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc

The following is a stripped-down version of the problem:

```
#include <initializer_list>
#include <iostream>

enum objects { zero, one, two, three, four, five, six, seven };

std::initializer_list<objects> objects_list()
{
    return { zero, one, two, three, four, five, six, seven };
}

int main()
{
    for (auto a : objects_list())
    {
        std::cout << a << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

My expectation is that the programs outputs:

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
```

which is comfirmed by GCC 4.9.2, but a GCC fresh from its git repository yields:

```
0 0 -85997960 32712 -1076836160 32765 0 32
```

which seem basically random numbers.

Is there a problem with my program or with GCC?

Comment: I have gcc 7.1.1 from late May, and I can't reproduce. Maybe some new pull request introduced this bug?

Comment: Although it doesn't matter here, I'd always prefer `for (const auto& a : ...` when you don't *need* a copy in the loop..

Comment: [Can reproduce here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/s40JCmvSLE8doIO2).  Very bizarre.

Comment: @Rakete1111: I used one of the online compilers and it seemed to work with everything but the newest GCC. I guess the crucial changes most have been introduced after 7.x ...

Comment: I'd suggest you package this up as part of a GCC bug report and then, for the currious of us, link the bug report in your question).

Comment: `std::initializer_list` is just a "view" of an array (which is a temporary created by the compiler, whose lifetime extended by the `std::initializer_list`, in the same way how a reference extend the lifetime of a temporary). It does not own the array. What this program does is comparable to returning a reference to temporary.

Comment: @cpplearner Are you sure? Because if I read the docs correctly, [they say otherwise](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list).

Comment: @cpplearner It does in C++14

Comment: I think cpplearner is right. From cppreference.com: `Initializer lists may be implemented as a pair of pointers or pointer and length. Copying a std::initializer_list does not copy the underlying objects.` ... Damn

Comment: Just FWIW, I think that the code works fine in GCC 4.9.2 is a symptom of [GCC bug 70167](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=70167), which is fixed by [r247793](https://gcc.gnu.org/viewcvs/gcc?view=revision&revision=247793).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

N4296 § 8.5.4/5 states

> An object of type `std::initializer_list<E>` is constructed from an initializer list as if the implementation
>   allocated a temporary array of `N` elements of type `const E`, where `N` is the number of elements in the
>   initializer list. Each element of that array is copy-initialized with the corresponding element of the initializer
>   list, and the `std::initializer_list<E>` object is constructed to refer to that array

So we're told that a `std::initializer_list` refers to a temporary array.

and § 8.5.4/6 states

> The array has the same lifetime as any other temporary object

And the standard provides this example to demonstrate that accessing an initializer list after its array has gone out of scope is undefined behavior:

```
struct A {
std::initializer_list<int> i4;
A() : i4{ 1, 2, 3 } {} // creates an A with a dangling reference
};
```

> the `initializer_list` object is initialized in a constructor’s
>   *ctor-initializer*, so the array persists only until the constructor exits, and so any use of the elements of `i4`
>   after the constructor exits produces undefined behavior. —end example ]

You have a similar, but slightly different, example that involves copying:

```
std::initializer_list<objects> objects_list()
{
    return { zero, one, two, three, four, five, six, seven };
}
```

By the logic from the standard, the array `{zero, one, two, ...}` only persists for the duration of the `objects_list` function.

18.9/2 [support.initlist] also supports that a copy will not persist the underlying array:

> Copying an [`std::`]`initializer list` does not copy the underlying elements.

So I believe your code is ultimately UB and the fact that it worked before was by luck.

Comment: Thanks. This shows that it always pays off to try new compilers and that I still don't understand C++ after all these years ...

Comment: @cschwan: You and me both. This question allowed me to learn a new thing about `std::initializer_list` and for that I thank you.

Comment: I have to say that this behaviour is quite a monstruosity

Comment: I don't think the behavior is as clear in C++17 with "guaranteed copy elision", because the return type is an rvalue, and if we say `auto x = objects_list()`, then "x" is initialized by the rvalue, which was initialized by `{ .. }`. I think that means that `x` is initialized by `{ .. }` which means that the array is still alive, since there's no intermediary object between the `return` statement and `x`'s initialization.

Comment: Therefore "and the std::initializer_list<E> object is constructed to refer to that array" would refer to object `x`, since that's the only `std::initializer_list<E>` object we got here.

Comment: A simple way to put it is that using a `std::initializer_list` as a wannabe container is a bad idea. (I can say that because I have been guilty of the same abuse, and I ran into the same problem.)

Comment: @Johannes The lifetime of the materialized array prvalue ends at the end of the return statement. So `objects_list()` still refers to an object whose lifetime has ended.